# Spring boot can't connect to websocket server using plain WebSocket API

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I am trying to set up a websocket connection from a brower plugin to my spring boot server. I can so far only setup a connection with socketJS like so:

`registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();`

but using plain websocket API in my code
`webSocketHandlerRegistry.addHandler(myHandler(),"/handler");`

doesn't allow me to connect with the native websocket api from a browser plugin. Why is that? And does somebody know the solution to this problem?

Source: WebSocketConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
  @Bean
  public WebSocketHandler myHandler() {
     return new MyHandler();
  }

  @Override
  public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry webSocketHandlerRegistry) {
     webSocketHandlerRegistry.addHandler(myHandler(), "/myHandler")
        .addInterceptors(new HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor());
  }
}
```

[documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server)

connection URL: ws://localhost:8080/myHandler

Comment: any error message? its pretty straight forward. https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Comment: Simply unable to connect I can use Java websocket just fine with the @ServerEndpoint annotation

Comment: There is not enough code shown to troubleshoot the issue.  This leads to guessing

Comment: The source is mostly taken straight from the documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server